# How to remove white space around checkbox (padding: 0px) using CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to create a 20px by 20px checkbox. I don't want the white area around it.

My css:

```
.box {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I tried box-sizing but it does not make a difference. Also, any idea why it looks like it is not centered?

Here is a picture of the problem I'm facing.
[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV8PC.png)

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand much about this, but I will try help. See this images:

1-https://ibb.co/Dfz2Vc3

2-https://ibb.co/vLBPZ6M

If I deleted the tag "whitespace" (I don't know if is it a tag because I didn't write it) and put zero on border on the input tag I will remove the white space around checkbox.

I don't know why I can't change the values 1.8, on the border...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.